# Input moves left when resizing windows

Tags: html, css, resize

My input and login button move to the left when my windows is resized, is it possible to keep them in one position ?
I am still new to html and css and still learning so any tips i'd appreciate.

Here is my css

```css
#absolute {
 position: absolute;
top: 411px;
left: 57%;
margin-left:-250px;
width: 600px; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have the html code as well?

Comment: Do you want them to keep certain distance from left edge of the window all the time? Post your HTML as @TonyTaiNguyen suggested.

Comment: Or do you want to keep them centered?  Please clarify "the same position."  Same position relative to what?

Comment: I was able to fix it with John Rusch's answer, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the issue has to do with that 57% in the 'left' attribute.  Since percent is based on the size of the parent element what's probably happening is the parent is changing size, and 57% of 1000px is different than 57% of 500px.  You should probably just change it to a pixel value, then it will hold still relative to the left side.

Also: I don't think you need than margin-left:-250px;  That's probably just competing with the 'left' attribute;

Comment: That was a silly mistake, thank you very much its working perfectly now.